# Unknown provider with AngularJS app on firebase hosting

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I've developed app (using code4startup tutorial), written on angularjs + bootstrap + firebase database and decided to host it on firebase.
I've done firebase init and firebase deploy...
I got a link https://sportpredictions.firebaseapp.com/#/, but nothing from angularjs doesn't work.
Console gives me mistakes like: 
Unknown provider: AuthProvider <- Auth <- NavController and 
AuthProvider <- Auth <- Prediction <- NavController
But on localhost everything is fine.
Maybe someone can help me to solve this problem, because I have already no idea what to do :(

Comment: I don't see auth.js in  your controllers directory. Are you sure you committed it?

Comment: It' there. Called Auth.js.
So really thing is that all js files which work well on my computer localhost doesn't work on firebase host at all. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference your AuthController file as auth.js (lower case a) in index.html but the file is  Auth.js (upper case A)